# Capitalize all files in a directory using Bash

Tags: macos, bash, rename

I have a directory called "Theme_1" and I want to capitalize all the filenames starting with "theme". The first letter of every file name is lowercase and I want it to be upcase.

I've tried this but all the letters in the filename are upcase, which is not what I want.

```
for f in * ; do mv -- "$f" "$(tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< "$f")" ; done
```

I also tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
mv theme*.jpg Theme*.jpg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Bash 4 you can use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) directly to capitalize every letter in a word (`^^`) or just the first letter (`^`).

```
for f in *; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f^}"
done
```

You can use patterns to form more sophisticated case modifications.

But for your specific question, aren't you working too hard? Just replace the word "theme" with the word "Theme" when it occurs at the beginning of filenames.

```
for f in theme*; do
    mv "$f" "Theme${f#theme}"
done
```

Comment: Thanks. The second solution worked for me, but not the first one which was returning ${f^}: bad substitution

Comment: @StefaniaF.Cardenas that probably means your bash is too old for those case-mod substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt was close but `tr` operates on every character in its input.

You either need to use something like `sed` that can operate on a single character or limit `tr` to only seeing the first character.

```
for f in * ; do
    mv -- "$f" "$(tr [:lower:] [:upper:] <<< "${f:0:1}")${f:1}"
done
```

That uses [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to only give `tr` the first character of the filename and then expand the rest of the filename after that.

Comment: This is helpful as well because now I know how to capitalise the first character for all the file names in my directory, but I accepted @kojiro answer because this one also changed the file names that do not start with "theme".

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get what I wanted in Bash. So I spent 2 minutes and got this working in PHP. This is for future googlers who are looking for a solution and happen to have PHP on their system.

```php
<?php

foreach(glob(__DIR__.'/*') as $filename) {
    if($filename === '.' || $filename === '..') { continue; }

    // To only capitalize the first letter of the file
    $new_filename = ucfirst(basename($filename));

    // To capitalize each word in the filename
    //$new_filename = ucwords(basename($filename));
    echo __DIR__.'/'.$new_filename."\n";
    rename($filename, __DIR__.'/'.$new_filename);
}
```